# iPhone tabs issue

Tags: iphone

I have made 5 tabs: `home`, `ask`, `tip of the day`, `inbox` and `disclaimer`. My problem is that the text `tip of the day` does not exactly fit inside the tab. I mean the `T` of tip and `Y` of day are getting out of the area of the tab. And it's looking absurd.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, you will just have to make the title shorter.